# Left pixels are cut off when viewing responsive site on smartphone

Tags: css

I am learning how to make an existing site, responsive and something that appears to be so simple, is making me absolutely crazy.
When I apply the max-width-480px style sheet, it is cutting off about 5 px of my left edge.  You can tell it is missing because the rounded corners I added in css are cut off abruptly on the left but are nice and smooth on the right.  I have spent several hours trying to tweak the wrapper and mainwrapper css and nothing seems to fix it.  Any ideas?

Note: that the image for the topwrapper is a set width white background with rounded corners.  Since the set sized graphic is not going to be responsive, I have removed it for the smaller screens and just added the border-radius to the mainwrapper div.

NOTE2:  I tried to add an image to show you the issue, but because I am a new poster, I was unable to.  The site is:  www.develdesign.com/WaterWorks  Please be sure to view it on your smartphone to see the issue.  Thank you.

**A snippet of the wrapper related divs in html**

```
    <body>
  <div id="wrapper">
    <div id="topwrapper"></div>
    <div id="mainwrapper">
      <!-- Header Start -->
      <div id="header">
        <div class="center">
          <!-- Logo Start -->
          <div id="logo"><a href="<?e(_WWW_)?>index.php"><img src="images/wworks/wwlogo239px.png" alt="logo" /></a></div>
          <!-- Logo End -->

          <div id="headerright">
            <!-- Menu Navigation Start -->

                                <? require('top-navigation.php'); ?>

            <!-- Menu Navigation End -->
          </div><!-- end headerright -->
        </div><!-- end center -->
      </div><!-- end header -->
```

**Regular Desktop Styles (non-responsive css)**

```
#wrapper {  
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 976px;
  height: 100%;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  margin-top: 20px;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}


#topwrapper {
  height: 19px;
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 976px;
  background: url(../images/topwrapper.png) no-repeat;
}
#mainwrapper {
    width:100%;
  max-width: 976px;
  background: url(../images/mainwrapper.png) repeat-y;
}
#bottomwrapper {
  margin: 0 auto;
  height: 55px;
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 976px;
  background: url(../images/bottomwrapper.png) no-repeat;
}
.center {
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 900px;
}

/* ----------------------- HEADER -----------------------*/
#header {
  width: 960px;
  height: 50px;
  padding-bottom: 39px;
  background: url(../images/bgheader.jpg) bottom center repeat-x;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
#headerright {
  padding-top: 20px;
  width: 670px;
  float: right;
    position: relative;
}
#logo {
  margin-top: 15px;
  float: left;
  width: 220px;
}
```

**Responsive for max-width-480px**

```
#wrapper {
    width: 100%;
    }

#topwrapper {
    display:none;
    }

#mainwrapper {    /*white background for all header and maincontent */
    border-radius: 5px 5px 25px 25px;
} 

#bottomwrapper {
  display: none;  
}


.maincontent {
    width: 60%;
    float: left;
}



<!-- HEADER -->
#header {
  /*width: 50%;*/
  /*height: 50%;*/
  /*background-image: none;*/
}

.center {
    width: 95%;
}

#headerright{  /* includes phone numbers and full site navmenu */
    display:none; 
}

#logo {
    width: 100%;
}
```

Comment: it's probably to do with margins and padding that are auto-added. Be sure to put margin:0!important; and padding:important; everywhere, not just in your media queries

Comment: you have your wrapper set to 100% i always set mine to 98

Comment: Thank you for your suggestions. Unfortunately adding 0!important didn't work.  I did change my wrapper to 98%.

Answer (score 0):

Can't say for sure but after a quick look, could it not be possible there is padding somewhere knocking it out. If so make sure to set the box-sizing attribute in your css.
Link:
[Box Sizing](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_box-sizing.asp)

Also check there is no whitespace between elements, this also effects display: inline-block in such a way that two divs at 50% width won't fit next to each other. You can either set line height to 0 or comment out the whitespace.

Comment: I searched through all of the css and there is no left padding and no inline-block on the divs on the main page.

Answer (score 0):

I finally figured it out!  The mainwrapper had a background image that was also a set width image (like the topwrapper).  Once I realized the mainwrapper's background image repeated only y, I removed it and replaced it with a background-color of white instead and it looks great.

```
  #mainwrapper {
  width:100%;
  max-width: 976px;
  background: url(../images/mainwrapper.png) repeat-y;
}
```